# error: expected identifier or '(' before 'public' - objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am getting this error when i declare my instance variable as

```
@interface FOO : NSObject
{
 @public
  int a;
}
@public
-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;
@end
```

error: expected identifier or '(' before 'public'

Comment: Why do you want to declare a public ivar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use `@public` or other access keywords outside the interface definition, as you don't declare public or private methods in Objective-C.

As long as you expose a method in a header/interface it's automatically publicly accessible from outside the class. If you only add an implementation, but don't expose it in the header/interface (or only expose it in a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html)), it's private.

```
@interface FOO : NSObject
{
@public
    int a;
}

- (id)init;
- (void)dealloc;

@end
```

Now why you would want to declare a public `int a` instance variable (instead of using a property) or explicitly declare two methods that `NSObject` already has is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

In objective-c methods block cannot contain @public (or @private) block - it is aplicable only to instance variable and all methods in objective-c classes are public, so to fix your error remove 2nd @public in your code:

```
@interface FOO : NSObject
{
 @public
  int a;
}
-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;
@end
```